# Golang web-server and concurrent approach for an in memory cache

Tags: go

I am not new to programming, but I am relatively new to golang and still not completely used to the golang concurrency approach.

The general set-up:

- Web server (should be fast and parallel), so I use net/http
- I need to store and retrieve lots of documents. While retrieving happens more often than storing, the factor is rather low. Maybe 20.
- When retrieving the, by far, most important are the lastly stored documents. The rest can be retrieved just from the disk/DB if needed.

  - Solution: In memory cache of last added items.
  - Note: On retrieval, I don't care about the last 3 seconds. Meaning, if, at time (A), I ask for a complete list of the last added items, the items added in the last 3 seconds can (partially or completely) be missing. But when asking again at time (A+3s) all those items should be in the list.

My question is related to how to implement the in memory cache.

### Naive approach #1 (RWLock)

- Have a big list of items in memory.
- Guard it with a RW lock

Problem with this approach: I successfully serialized the web server :)

OK, please forget about this approach.

### Approach #2: Split things up

- have X lists in memory (each with RWLock)
- on http handler start get a random number and chose one of the X lists, work only on that list
- Another collector routine is started every 2.5 seconds collecting and combining the lists

This is better, I theoretically could even split the work between servers.

But, for example based on the golang tour code:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/view/", makeHandler(viewHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/edit/", makeHandler(editHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/save/", makeHandler(saveHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**How do I pass/get a new random number in the http handler without serializing?**

- It does not need to be cryptographically secure. I just want to use it to pick one of the X lists.
- I know there is a global random generator but that uses a mutex internally, so back to square 1.
- I could ask the clients (JavaScript) to provide a random number as get parameter. But that sounds dangerous (DOS)? Or is this OK?
- I might not know the users IP address in the go server (reverse proxy setup).

And: **Generally is this a good approach? Is there a better way?** And now I am limiting myself to X, this does not scale. If I want X to change during run-time, how could I tell the handlers about that change (without becoming serial again)?

Comment: What "lastly stored documents" does mean, ie how long do you keep an document in cache (IOW consider it "lastly stored")?

Comment: With "lastly stored" I mean the last, say 200, items uploaded by the users. (I know that, with heavy traffic, that is not very useful. But part of the problem is giving the user a random item back. Additionally the problem in the question is something I want to solve to better understand how to use go)

Comment: COrrect me if I'm wrong but you are trying to create a sharded hashtable to prevent locking all the hashtable when you set a value by set I mean create/update/delete) but at the same time you don't want add a master lock when you try to create a new sharded hashtable when it doesn't exist?

Comment: Or put another way: Having X shards, how do I distribute the handlers spawned by net/http.ListenAndServe evenly to them. Is there some kind of per handler ID I can use? (I hope I use the word shard correctly).

Comment: Or put another way, I want web handlers that work in parallel but can access global data (that is synchronized only from time to time). But possibly without using a master lock that all handlers have to acquire at start. The problem is that the handlers are short lived goroutines that are started somewhere in net/http and I don't know how to do the synchronization/distribution without said lock.

Comment: I read up on sharded hash tables. I think they are different from what I want to implement. Some clients are adding items. And some clients want to get random or the last X items. The retrieving client obviously don't know the contents/key of the items. So I don't think I can use a hash table for that.

Comment: I found this: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt32 , that could be used to create a new value per handler. It would still be a central value shared between different goroutines. But it probably is really fast?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really serialize your server with **RWLock**. Use `RLock()` for parallel read of documents.

Check on [thread-safe concurrent map for go](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map) library. It utilizes mutex and sharding technics alongside. I would also added CQRS to database level and It could easily handle 100K concurrent requests/sec.